# Can't register, got 403 error

Tags: imgur

I am trying to register an account on Imgur. But got 403 error:

> Sorry! There was an error (code: 403) retrieving the page you requested. Try refreshing or double checking your URL. If you think this error is an error, try contacting us about it.

[image]

I tried multiple times, but got same error.